# how to change column name using apply()

Tags: python

I'd like to rename column name and I define a function. I am thinking how to apply this function to whole columns names.

```
def fix_wellname(well):
    well_num=int(well.split('A')[0])
    pad_name=well.split('A')[1]
    
    well_name_fixed=str(well_num)+'A'+pad_name
    return well_name_fixed
```

if I do like below:

```
df.columns=df.columns.apply(fix_wellname)

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df.columns = [fix_wellname(c) for c in df.columns]
```

Or if mapping the function is somehow a requirement, try:

```
df.columns = map(fix_wellname, df.columns)
```

Comment: Thank you Grismar, 2nd one is the one I needed. I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome, if this answers your question, feel free to click the checkmark, so the question no longer appears as unanswered